# How to calculate $\lim_{x \to0} \dfrac{f(x)-f(\ln(1+x))}{x^{3}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, limits, logarithms

$f$ is a differntiable function on $[-1,1]$ and doubly differentiable  on $x=0$ and $f^{'}(0)=0,f^{"}(0)=4$.

How to calculate $$\lim_{x \to0} \dfrac{f(x)-f\big(\ln(1+x)\big)}{x^{3}}.
$$

I have tried the L'Hosptial's rule, but get trouble with the form of 
$$\lim_{x \to 0}f^{"}(x)-\dfrac {f^{"}\big(\ln(1+x)\big)}{(1+x)^2},$$
it may not exist.

Comment: Does differentiable/twice differentiable imply continuous? Trying out this problem now...

Comment: Maybe you should make use of $f'(a) = \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$? (if that's even right)

Comment: The answers are looking more complicated. Can you provide context of the problem? Maybe this is in the section of a chapter of a Real Analysis book rather than a Calculus book?

Comment: @BCLC It's a sample question of a calculus mid-term before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Answer.** The value of the limit is $\,\,\dfrac{f''(0)}{2}=2$.

**Hint.** Mean Value Theorem provides that
$$
f(x)-f\big(\log (1+x)\big)=\big(x-\log(1+x)\big)\,f'\big(\xi(x)\big),
$$
for some $\xi(x)\in\big(\log(1+x),x\big)$. Then
$$
\frac{f(x)-f(\log (1+x))}{x^3}=\frac{x-\log(1+x)}{x^2}\cdot\frac{f'(\xi(x))}{\xi(x)}\cdot
\frac{\xi(x)}{x}.
$$
Then $\dfrac{x-\log(1+x)}{x^2}\to \dfrac{1}{2}$ (L'Hopital), $\dfrac{f'(\xi(x))}{\xi(x)}=\dfrac{f'(\xi(x))-f'(0)}{\xi(x)}\to f''(0)$, and
$\dfrac{\xi(x)}{x}\to 1$, since $\log(1+x)<\xi(x)<x$.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use l'Hôpital's rule, but be careful with the chain rule:

First step:
$$L = \lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x)-f(\ln(1+x))}{x^3} = \lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{f^\prime(x)-\frac{f^\prime(\ln(1+x))}{1+x}}{3x^2}.$$
Second step:
$$L = \lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{f^{\prime\prime}(x) - \frac{f^{\prime\prime}(\ln(1+x))}{(1+x)^2}+\frac{f^\prime(\ln(1+x))}{(1+x)^2}}{6x}.$$
Third step:
$$L = \lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{f^{\prime\prime\prime}(x)-\frac{f^{\prime\prime\prime}(\ln(1+x))}{(1+x)^2}+\frac{2f^{\prime\prime}(\ln(1+x))}{(1+x)^3}+\frac{f^{\prime\prime}(\ln(1+x))}{(1+x^2)}-\frac{2f^\prime(\ln(1+x))}{(1+x^3)}}{6}$$
Hence:
$$L = \frac{3f^{\prime\prime}(0)-2f^\prime(0)}{6}=\frac{12}{6}=2.$$

Comment: Does the line after "hence" have to do with $f'(a) = lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a}$?

Comment: @BCLC: It's simply substituting $x=0$.

Comment: This matches with my answer. We have to be careful, as given, that $f'(0)=0$, or else L'Hospital cannot be used to get the third step (since the numerator does not go to $0$). I only mention this since you carried the $f'(0)$ to your final answer (if $f'(0)\ne0$, your formula is not correct).

Comment: @robjohn: That is true. B.t.w., it's l'Hôpital and not L'Hospital.

Comment: Why can we take the third order derivative for $f(x)$?

Comment: @SPK: The person's name may have been l'Hôpital, but the name of the rule has been propagated as both [l'Hôpital](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) and [L'Hospital](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LHospitalsRule.html) in the literature. I am lazy and use L'Hospital so that I don't have to type ô :-)

Comment: @John ZHANG: What do you mean? Why would be not able to take the hird order derivative?

Comment: @robjohn: Alrighty then.

Comment: @SPK Because OP only assumes $f$ be differentiable on $[-1,1]$. So the second order derivative may not exist except at $x=0$

Comment: Good point. Maybe it's allowed because it cancels out anyway, but I have to admit that doesn't sound like a solid argument.

Comment: Likewise for the second derivative elsewhere than at 0.

Answer (score 1):

Using MVT :

$$\lim_{x \to0} \dfrac{f(x)-f(ln(1+x))}{x^{3}} =\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{f(x)-f(0)+f(\ln 1)-f(ln(1+x))}{x^{3}} = \lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{xf'(\theta_1 x)-x[f(\ln (1+\theta_2 x)]'}{x^{3}} $$

Comment: What are the $\theta$s?

Comment: $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2 \in [0,1]$

Comment: How is this going to provide the desired limit?